# Solr 4.10.2 - DataImportHandler - Qustion

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a question on loading data into Solr using DataImportHandler.

I have a xml file which I need to load into Solr using data import handler via Xpath transformer:

XML file structure is:

```
<record>
    <item>
        <tags>
            <tag1>
                <tag>
                    <id>01</id>
                    <value>value01</value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <id>02</id>
                    <value>value02</value>
                </tag>
            <tag1>
            <tag2>
                <tag>
                    <id>03</id>
                    <value>value03</value>
                </tag>              
            <tag2>
            <tag3>
                <tag>
                    <id>04</id>
                    <value>value04</value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <id>05</id>
                    <value>value05</value>
                </tag>
                <tag>
                    <id>06</id>
                    <value>value06</value>
                </tag>              
            <tag3>              
        </tags>
    </item>
</record>
```

I can use ***/record/item/tags//tag/id*** to load the data in a multivalue field but I need to maintain the relationship of id with value, I mean I need a way, so that at query time I can get the value related to id.

Please advice. Thanks in advance.